# product variation switcher

Tags: 7, commerce

Hy Drupal Masters!

My question is about commerce module.
I managed to do the followings:

- create taxonomies (for creating menu and categorizing products - type - , AND for classifying products in other context - package)
- create product types
- create the appropiate content types to product types
- creating product variations(variations based on 2 fields in content types: "type" and "package" )

For example
I have 3 menu-category with products: prod1(products of category: prod1-1, prod1-2, prod1-3), prod2(prod2-1, prod2-2, prod2-3), prod3(prod3-1, prod3-2, prod3-3)

Each product in one category has 3 variation: small, medium, large
At the moment, if I click one of the categories, the product list appear with the good products, and each product has only one variation. 
(eg. I click prod1, I'll see the products, like: prod1-1small, prod1-2small, prod1-3small)

How I expected...but:

I wold like to place a selector(select list or checkboxes, I don't mind) to the top of the product list under each category that is containing small, medium, large elements. Than if I select "medium", the product list needed to change according to the selection.(I would like to see the: prod1-1medium, prod1-2medium, prod1-3medium)

In a product details page I could do this, but in a product list page, I couldn't.

I am using drupal 7

Please somebody help me!

Comment: The "type" term-reference-field is defined at content types, and the "package" term-reference-field is defined at product types, beacuse of the variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this.

First: I have just created one product type, with the field 'somethingTermReference'(term reference), wich will be the base of the production switcher.

Second: I created content types for every product category, for displaying them. Each content type has a type field with distinct values.

Third: I created views for every product category and there are 3 filter criterias for each view: published content, content type(actual product category), and one exposed filter on a product reference 'somethingTermReference' field.